# Rails: When does the fingerprint on assets change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, the asset pipeline will add a fingerprint to any compiled CSS and JS. e.g. `/assets/application-eb091fbd069aa77a89d039e9ac6931aa.css`.

My question is, when does this fingerprint change, is it any time you deploy to prod, or does it only change if the pipeline detects some differences in code to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails asset pipeline fingerprints are [based on the content of the file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark), so they change when the content changes